# Unable to use the function by importing function's file in Python

Tags: python, pycharm

I am learning Python. I don't know what is going wrong in my code.
The problem I am facing is that I have a python file named `MyFile.py` with below-given contents.

```
def add(a,b):
    return a + b

def mul(c,d):
    return c * d
```

File Saved in a location.

Next, I open a new Python File in Pycharm and written the below code.

```
import myfile

print(myfile.mul(2,3))
print(myfile.add(2,3))
```

When I run the code the output I got is as following:

```
~/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python ~/PycharmProjects/untitled/myfile.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Nothing is output. Can anyone help me what is going wrong?

Comment: no Import errors?

Comment: You are running `myfile.py` which has your function definition. Why would it print anything? You should instead run the file where you are calling those functions

Comment: run it in IDLE and give us the output

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `myfile` according to your output and this file has no output (only functions definitions):

`~/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python ~/PycharmProjects/untitled/myfile.py`

If you are using `Pycharm`, switch to the file you want to run -> right-click -> `Run <your_file_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Run the file in which you are importing the myfile.py

Eg - If your new file name is calculate.py

you should run :

```
~/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python ~/PycharmProjects/untitled/calculate.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing wrong file.
As per your output you are executing `myfile.py`

myfile.py only has two functions defined in them. Nothing else. No code to print something to console.

The printing code is as you say written in new file created by you. Try running that new file with print statements.